# Why my maven module could not find another module in the project?

Tags: java, maven

Here is the main pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.smsoffice</groupId>
    <artifactId>sms-office</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SMS office</name>
    <modules>
        <module>sms-office-core</module>
        <module>sms-office-ui</module>
        <module>sms-office-webapp</module>
    </modules>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>${distribution.repository.id}</id>
            <name>Artifactory Release</name>
            <url>${distribution.repository.url}</url>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>${snapshot.repository.id}</id>
            <name>Artifactory Snapshot</name>
            <url>${snapshot.repository.url}</url>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

<!--    <repositories> -->
<!--        <repository> -->
<!--            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id> -->
<!--            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name> -->
<!--            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url> -->
<!--            <layout>default</layout> -->
<!--        </repository> -->
<!--    </repositories> -->

  <properties>
    <wicket.version>1.4.9</wicket.version>
    <wicket.auth-roles.version>1.4.3</wicket.auth-roles.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>branch</id>
            <properties>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                <release-plugin.tagBase>${scm.connection}/mps/sms-office/releases</release-plugin.tagBase>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <scm>
      <connection>scm:svn:http://cvs:8383/repositories/sms-office/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://cvs:8383/repositories/sms-office/trunk</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0-beta-9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>${release-plugin.tagBase}</tagBase>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Implementation-Version>${BUILD_TAG}</Build-Implementation-Version>
                            <Build-Number>${BUILD_NUMBER}</Build-Number>
                            <Build-ID>${BUILD_ID}</Build-ID>
                            <Revision>${buildNumber}</Revision>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Implementation-Version>${BUILD_TAG}</Build-Implementation-Version>
                            <Build-Number>${BUILD_NUMBER}</Build-Number>
                            <Build-ID>${BUILD_ID}</Build-ID>
                            <Revision>${buildNumber}</Revision>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.5</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.5</targetJdk>
                    <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
                    <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Here is the pom of moduleA - sms-office-core:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.smsoffice</groupId>
        <artifactId>sms-office</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sms-office-core</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>sms office core</name>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>live</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <copy file="src/main/profiles/live.database.properties"
                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/database.properties" />
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <copy file="src/main/profiles/local.database.properties"
                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/database.properties" />
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jotm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jotm</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsecurity</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsecurity</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xom</groupId>
            <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and moduleB - sms-office-ui

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.smsoffice</groupId>
        <artifactId>sms-office</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sms-office-ui</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>sms office ui</name>
    <description>sms office ui</description>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/resources</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make shared resources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/resources.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Project Internal Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>sms-office-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- External dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-auth-roles</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.auth-roles.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I can make mvn clean install on the moduleA with no problems. But I cannot make it in the second module. When I try to make mvn install on sms-office-ui maven give me error:

Failed to execute goal on project sms-office-ui: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.smsoffice:sms-office-ui:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.smsoffice:sms-office-core:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.smsoffice:sms-office-core:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.smsoffice:sms-office:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

My question is how to locate the sms-office-core in order show maven where is its location?

Answer (score 1):

You should not compile the module itself. You need to issue the `mvn` commands on the root. Then, you can specify that you would like to build a single module, with the `--pl` option. Also, you need the `--am` to build the dependent modules. So, the command becomes:

```
mvn install -pl sms-office-ui -am
```

By the way `--pl` is the shorthand for `--projects` and `--am` for `--also-make`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's having trouble resolving the parent pom.  Ensure that you're running `mvn clean install` from the parent directory so that it installs the parent pom before it tries to build the child.